# What "news" is Yusuf referring to?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Mustafa Kama's son, Yusuf, says to Corvus, whose late father killed Yusuf's family:

> So he confided you to his servant, who boarded a ship for America. His
>   servant,  Irma Dugard, was a half-elf. Her magic was weak, and
>   therefore left no trace I could  follow. I had only just discovered
>   how you had escaped when I received **news** I never expected.

What "news" is Yusuf referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## That Leta and Corvus survived the ship sinking.

Right after Yusuf Kama mentions getting news he’d never expected, he says he’d heard that the ship Leta and Corvus Jr. were on sank, but both Leta and Corvus Jr. survived its sinking.

> **KAMA**
>
> His servant, Irma Dugard, was a half-elf. Her magic was weak and therefore left no trace I could follow. **I had only just discovered how you had escaped when I received news I never expected . . . The ship had gone down at sea . . . But you survived, didn’t you?** 
> *(to CREDENCE)* 
> Somehow, someone had pulled you from the water!
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

Presumably, that the ship Leta and Corvus Jr. were on sank but they (particularly Corvus Jr.) were pulled from the water and survived is the news Yusuf Kama was referring to. He continues on to quote a prophecy, and his interpretation that Credence is the “winged raven returned from the water”.

> *(to CREDENCE)* Somehow, someone had pulled you from the water!
>
> “A son cruelly banished
>
> Despair of the daughter
>
> Return, great avenger 
> With wings from the water.” 
> There—
> *(points at LETA)* 
> stands the despairing daughter. You are the winged raven returned from the sea, but I—I am the avenger of my family’s ruin.

The news Yusuf Kama says he never expected is that Leta and Corvus Jr. were on a ship that sank but survived, which he believed meant that particular prophecy was about his situation.

Comment: The quote by itself is ambiguous, he could mean Leta and Corvus surviving, or he could mean the ship sinking.  The latter seems more natural given the phrasing, but perhaps it is ruled out by the timeline?  I don't recall the sequence of events well enough to tell.